# Comparing one column of cells to another

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a list of 20,000+ email addresses in one column and a similarly sized column of emails I want to compare. I want to flag entries in the first column that also appear in the second. I wrote this code to make it happen:

```
Sub macro()

Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long

i = 2

For i = 2 To 27934

n = 2

For n = 2 To 20824

If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(n, 7) Then
    Cells(i, 3) = 1

End If

Next n

Next i

End Sub
```

It's telling me 'type mismatch'. I tried a few other options, like a while loop. I'm sure there are a million other ways to get this done, but I can't figure it out. Anybody got a minute to help?

Comment: Cells() gets an object, you have to get the value from the object. Try cells(i, 1).value. The type mismatch is probably you assigning the cell object to the value 1.

Comment: One note, you don't need to assign `i = 2` before for loop as you do this in the beginning of the loop itself. So leaving code lines 4 & 6 out works the same, but is actually more "efficient".

Comment: You're code works for me (I copy/pasted your code exactly). Perhaps you have some unusual data or objects in your sheet. Can you post more details?

Comment: I put a few different things in there trying to break it, and it looks like you can throw a type mismatch if you have a broken formula in one of the cells; at least as one example: =test broke the compare

Comment: You can use IsError(Cells(i, 1)) to skip cells that may contain error values. Alternatively, you can use On Error Resume Next to ignore these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data is in ColumnsA (to be flagged) and B, starting in Row2:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A2,B:B,0),"")
```

in C2 and copied down should "get the job done", and relatively quickly.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to append the second list to the first and do (Home ribbon) conditional formatting --> highlight cell rules --> duplicate values